# Asynchronous re-rendering with Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, template-engine, nunjucks

I use precompiled template files which are rendered synchronously, and I want to re-render blocks of data in those templates. Is this possible and if so, how is this best done?

An example:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ synchronousTitle }}</h1>

    {% block aSyncAjaxData %}
        <div>
            <h1>Search for {{ phrase }}</h1>

            <div class="results">
                {% for result in searchResults %}
                    <div class="result">
                        ... Loop album results
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The block ajaxData is rendered empty first (which works using the block tag), and should be re-rendered with asynchronous data.

Answer (score 1):

In the last versions of Nunjucks this possible use the Asynchronous Rendering writing Async Loaders and Extensions see: http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#asynchronous

Comment: Will you elaborate with example with some code . Suppose you will fire a db  query and want to render that data using async loading how would you achieve this in html and backend part.